# Screen Sharing with VNC -- is it on?

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm using OS 10.11.1. I turned on Screen Sharing:
[image]

and disabled "VNC viewers may control screen with password":
[image]

But as you can see, it still says "Other users can access your computer's screen at vnc://...". Does that mean that, when "VNC viewers may control screen with password" is unchecked, VNC viewers can control my screen WITHOUT a password?
Or does it mean that VNC is disabled?

(Ideally I'd like to allow VNC over SSH, rather than with a password.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are safe. Anyone that requests vnc://192.168.1.100 has to enter both an existing user name and the matching password for that user.

If you enable the anyone may request, then the incoming request is shown and you make the choice to enable the sharing. Until you accept, no view happens.

If you enable the VNC password then it's like a guest account where the user name is not checked but that password will show the screen contents.